# Get attribute from URL using Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to get attribute from URL using Thymeleaf.
 For example, for URL: 
http://somedomain/university/auditories/findAll 
http://somedomain/university/subjects/findAll 
How can I get a keyword from URL (auditories or subjects)?

Answer (score 0):

I found answer,

gives what I wanted - transforms to  http://localhost:8080/subjects/delete
now I can remove a lot of duplicated html

I have a lot of similar pages (students, auditories, subjects etc) which has the same functions: add, delete, so I had to use very similar add/delete modals like this:

```
<div th:fragment="addModal" class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <form th:action="@{/students/add}"  //this line is choosing which controller to call (my old version)
 <form th:action="@{__${#httpServletRequest.requestURI}__/add}" //new version   (now I can use same modal for different pages)
 method="post">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">New</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <label for="name" class="col-form-label">Enter name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And this is controller class (controllers for other objects are very similar):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/subjects")
public class SubjectController {

   @Autowired
    SubjectService subjectService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getAll(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("subjects", subjectService.getAll());
        return "subjects";
}

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String add(Subject subject) {
        subjectService.add(subject);
        return "redirect:/subjects/";
    }

    @PostMapping("/delete")
    public String delete(Subject subject) {
        subjectService.delete(subject);
        return "redirect:/subjects/";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer, and provide your solution? Thanks!